# Are there any C++ tools that detect misuse of static_cast, dynamic_cast, and reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, casting, static-analysis, downcast, dynamic-analysis

The answers to the following question describe the recommended usage of `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, and `reinterpret_cast` in C++:

[When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

Do you know of any tools that can be used to detect misuse of these kinds of cast? Would a static analysis tool like PC-Lint or Coverity Static Analysis do this?

The particular case that prompted this question was the inappropriate use of `static_cast` to downcast a pointer, which the compiler does not warn about. I'd like to detect this case using a tool, and not assume that developers will never make this mistake.

Comment: Using static_cast to downcast pointers is fine, and recommended if you know that it is the right sub-class that you're casting to.

Comment: That's an appropriate use of static_cast. I'm looking for a tool that will detect inappropriate use (where it's the wrong sub-class that I'm casting to).

Comment: The problem is that the particular case where `static_cast` scape the information available in the code (you may know from invariants in your design that the cast will be correct even if the information is not present in code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that there is no reliable way of telling what type the pointer points to at compile time, this is a pretty hard problem to catch at compile time.

The simplest method is to do the catch at run-time, using a macro "safe_cast" which compiles to a dynamic_cast with an assert in debug, and a static_cast in release.

Now, during debugging, if the cast is inappropriate, the dynamic cast will return NULL, and assert.  There is also no overhead during release.

Answer (score 4):

Visual studio has warnings for some of these.  C4946, for example.  They're mostly turned off by default though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23k5d385.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Boost offers polymorphic_pointer_downcast() and polymorphic_downcast() functions, which act like static_cast but will assert (typically only in debug builds) if the equivalent dynamic_cast fails.

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/conversion/cast.htm for details.